# How to create static block for customer login in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create a static block on homepage in right side  for user login. Please see the below screen short:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nviws.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Try to update a layout XML file `app/design/frontend/*DEFAULT*/*DEFAULT*/layout/`.

You also may create your own local.xml file and put it in the contents.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <reference name="right">
      <block type="your/type" template="path/to/your/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```